# Visual Studio working in C# Find And Replace using external list

Tags: c#

I have a C# custom coded strategy for NinjaTrader in a .cs file, the newest version of NinjaTrader breaks the code as many of the methods, functions, etc have been renamed. Is it possible to use a CSV file or other format, that can be used in a "Find and Replace", to change the values listed in the CSV, within the .cs file?

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Anything is possible, given enough time, money and caffeine.  What are you really asking?

Comment: I do not believe Visual Studio “Find and Replace” has a mechanism to accept a feed file.  But nothing is stop you from creating one.  I believe the simplest approach is to just create another program to perform the updates you need using the CSV file as a driver file.  You can also investigate authoring your own extension to VS: https://code.visualstudio.com/api

Comment: By the time you'd written such a thing (or even created the csv) it you probably would have been able to work through the errors list with repeated `Ctrl + .` rename refactoring and sort it all out

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Notepad++ for these types of edits.  It has a "Find in Files" function that facilitates this, including support for RegEx patterns and replacements.

Be careful however with what you change, especially if making changes to the NT's .csproj file.  NT can be sensitive to changes.  And of course, make sure that things compile properly.